# Getting generated video to next view and saving it to Camera roll in iOS

Tags: ios, video, uiimage

Here I need to generate video with multiple images picked,music selected.In this I can pick multiple images and generate video to those images By saving selected images in an array and generating video.But my issue is, generated video should present in next view and also it should be saved in CameraRoll.But the generated video is going to Documents and saving there.Someone help me..

I'm following this link
https://github.com/caferrara/img-to-video

My code:

```
 NSError *error = nil;
 NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory()
 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
 NSString *videoOutputPath = [documentsDirectory      stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test_output.mp4"];
 if ([fileMgr removeItemAtPath:videoOutputPath error:&error] != YES)
    NSLog(@"Unable to delete file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
   CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(400, 200);
   NSUInteger fps = 30;
  NSArray* imagePaths = [[NSBundle mainBundle]   pathsForResourcesOfType:@"jpg" inDirectory:nil];
 self.chosenImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]   initWithCapacity:imagePaths.count];
 NSLog(@"-->imageArray.count= %i", self.chosenImages.count);
  for (NSString* path in imagePaths)
  {
    [self.chosenImages addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]];

 }

 NSLog(@"Start building video from defined frames.");

  AVAssetWriter *videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:
  [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoOutputPath]  fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
                                                          error:&error];
  NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);

   NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
   [NSNumber numberWithInt:imageSize.width],   AVVideoWidthKey,
   [NSNumber numberWithInt:imageSize.height], AVVideoHeightKey,
                               nil];

   AVAssetWriterInput* videoWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput
    assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                        outputSettings:videoSettings];
   AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor =    [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor
 assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:videoWriterInput
sourcePixelBufferAttributes:nil];
 NSParameterAssert(videoWriterInput);
 NSParameterAssert([videoWriter canAddInput:videoWriterInput]);
 videoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
 [videoWriter addInput:videoWriterInput];
 [videoWriter startWriting];
 [videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];

CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;

//convert uiimage to CGImage.
int frameCount = 0;
double numberOfSecondsPerFrame = 6;
double frameDuration = fps * numberOfSecondsPerFrame;

//for(VideoFrame * frm in imageArray)
NSLog(@"**************************************************");
for(UIImage * img in self.chosenImages)
{
    //UIImage * img = frm._imageFrame;
    buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[img CGImage]];

    BOOL append_ok = NO;
    int j = 0;
    while (!append_ok && j < 30) {
        if (adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData)  {
            //print out status:
            NSLog(@"Processing video frame (%d,%lu)",frameCount,(unsigned long)[self.chosenImages count]);

            CMTime frameTime = CMTimeMake(frameCount*frameDuration,(int32_t) fps);
            append_ok = [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:frameTime];
            if(!append_ok){
                NSError *error = videoWriter.error;
                if(error!=nil) {
                    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@,%@.", error, [error userInfo]);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("adaptor not ready %d, %d\n", frameCount, j);
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
        }
        j++;
    }
    if (!append_ok) {
        printf("error appending image %d times %d\n, with error.", frameCount, j);
    }
    frameCount++;
}
NSLog(@"**************************************************");

//Finish the session:
[videoWriterInput markAsFinished];
[videoWriter finishWriting];
NSLog(@"Write Ended");



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////  OK now add an audio file to move file  /////////////////////
AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

NSString *bundleDirectory = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
// audio input file...
NSString *audio_inputFilePath = [bundleDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"30secs.mp3"];
NSURL    *audio_inputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audio_inputFilePath];

// this is the video file that was just written above, full path to file is in --> videoOutputPath
NSURL    *video_inputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoOutputPath];

// create the final video output file as MOV file - may need to be MP4, but this works so far...
NSString *outputFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"final_video.mp4"];
NSURL    *outputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputFilePath];

   if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:outputFilePath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:outputFilePath error:nil];

  CMTime nextClipStartTime = kCMTimeZero;

  AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset  alloc]initWithURL:video_inputFileUrl options:nil];
    CMTimeRange video_timeRange =    CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,videoAsset.duration);
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *a_compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition   addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo     preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [a_compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:video_timeRange ofTrack:      [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0]   atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];

  //nextClipStartTime = CMTimeAdd(nextClipStartTime, a_timeRange.duration);

    AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:audio_inputFileUrl  options:nil];
    CMTimeRange audio_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration);
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *b_compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
   [b_compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:audio_timeRange ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];
   AVAssetExportSession* _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
   //_assetExport.outputFileType = @"com.apple.quicktime-movie";
   _assetExport.outputFileType = @"public.mpeg-4";
  //NSLog(@"support file types= %@", [_assetExport supportedFileTypes]);
  _assetExport.outputURL = outputFileUrl;

  [_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
   ^(void ) {
     //[self saveVideoToAlbum:outputFilePath];
   }
   ];

   NSLog(@"DONE.....outputFilePath--->%@", outputFilePath);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also fetch your video in next screen by your document path.

You may store your video from Documents folder to PhotoLibrary by executing below code.

```
ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetLibrary writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:DocumentPath completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
  If(error == nil){
   // Saved successfully
  }
}];
```

Comment: check DocumentPath and it should be NSUrl.

Comment: before it used display path where the video is saved but now getting exception   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: This exception is from your code. Some array is blank and you are accessing it.

Comment: but Yesterday i didn't get any exception and I'm using same code

Comment: Comment my code and check again. Do some debug by putting breakpoint and you can rectify it

Comment: already commented your code ..i'm getting exception in this line   [a_compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:video_timeRange ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];

Comment: Seems your library has error. Check your libary code or raise bug in github to solve it out.

Comment: Before I didn't get any exception while generating video.:(

Comment: Remove derived data, clean your simulator and try again. :)

Comment: ya just now done that thing and running my application,actually I'm using elcimagepicker to pick images